# Стоит ли использовать ELK только ради логов?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Проект достаточно крупный. Ведется лог real-time интеграции, служб доставки и платежей.
На текущий момент логи пишутся в файлы. Стоит ли для этого использовать elastic stack ?

Т.к. логи у нас пишутся постоянно, не будут ли они тормозить, если отправлять в logstash, который на другом сервере ?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что понимать под тормозами, если просто писать логи -то достаточно минимально рекомендуемой конфигурации. А если предполагается в кибане постоянно что-то искать тяжелыми вайлдкарт-запросами, много визуализаций и дашбордов -то здесь все упрется в цпу, память и количество нод. Опять же все индивидуально, какие таймауты на это все для вас приемлемы.

Возможно вам логстеш и не нужен, посмотрите мидлвар пакеты логирования для ваших фреймворков, они сейчас есть практически для всего. У нас проект на aspnet core, и мы для логов используем serilog, который напрямую пишет в эластик, минуя логстеш.

Будьте также внимательны к самим логами, т.к. документы в эластике типизированные, можно запросто потерять какие-то логи, если уже существуют поля другого типа. Например приложение в одно месте пишет лог с полем MySuperId с типом Int, а потом появляется необходимость писать такой же MySuperId но с другого места и с типом string, вот здесь и начинаются проблемы. Но это все решаемо через Reindex API эластика.